# How to interpret multiple XSD key/keyref on an XML attribute

Tags: xsd, foreign-keys, key

Given the following XML element structure:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c test_id="1"/>
        <d test_ref="1"/>
    </b>
    <e>
        <c test_id="12"/>
    </e>
<a>
```

and the following XSD rules:

-) in Element a:

```
<xsd:key name="key_A">
    <xsd:selector xpath=".//c"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="@test_id"/>
</xsd:key>
<xsd:keyref name="keyref_A" refer="key_A"">
  <xsd:selector xpath=".//d"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="test_id"/>
</xsd:keyref>
```

-) in Element b:

```
<xsd:key name="key_B">
  <xsd:selector xpath=".//c"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="@test_id"/>
</xsd:key>
<xsd:keyref name="keyref_B" refer="key_B"">
  <xsd:selector xpath=".//d"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="test_id"/>
</xsd:keyref>
```

- When I set test_ref to "12" I get a validation error.
- When I set test_ref to "1" I get no error.

How are multiple keys/keyrefs interpreted? Does every keyref needs to be valid? Do I get not error when I set it to "1" because it satisfies both keys?

There are already questions regarding this topic but none explains how it is evaluated by a parser.

Comment: Neither `c` nor `d` is a child of `a`, and neither of them has a child named `test_id`.  I don't see how any of the constraints you've defined on element `a` can ever fire.  And since none of your constraints applies to anything named `test_ref`, I don't see how you can possibly be getting the error you describe with the example you provide.   I appreciate your attempt to provide a minimal working example, but if it doesn't generate the results you describe, it's not a working example.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question by changing the xpath to .//

Comment: ... leaving both keyref_A and keyref_B vacuously satisfied because there are no elements matching the expression `self::a//d/test_id` or the expression `self::b//d/test_id` which fail to satisfy the constraint.  Still doesn't look like a working example to me.    I can recommend the advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html);  good luck!